# Is it possible to find matrices $M, N$ such that $MXN$ has specified structure for all $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $M \in \mathbb R^{2 \times *}$ and $N \in \mathbb R^{\# \times 2}$. Here $*$ and $\#$ means we can pick any dimension we want. The end goal is to  find fixed $M, N$ such that range of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^{* \times \#} \to \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ given by $X \mapsto MXN$ is the $1$-dim space spanned by $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}$. I tried to pick $* = 1, 2$ and $\#= 1, 2$ but with no luck. Is this even possible?

Comment: What if $X=0$ and $\alpha \neq 0$?

Comment: @parsiad: Sorry, this is unclear formulation. I really mean: can we find fixed $M, N$ such that range of linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^{* \times \#} \to \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ given by $X \mapsto MXN$ is the $1$-dim space spanned by $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible unless you accept that the range is $\{0\}$. Consider first the case $1,1$. We have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} M_{11}\\ M_{21}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} N_{11}&N_{12}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $M_{11}N_{11}=0$. If $M_{11}\ne0$, then $N_{11}=0$. But then $a=M_{21}N_{11}=0$. From the $1,2$ entry, $0=a=M_{11}N_{12}$, $N_{12}=0$ and $N=0$. When $N_{11}=0$, we obtain similarly that $M=0$ (just take transpose and apply the argument).

Now in general, if $E_{kj}$ is the matrix with $1$ in the $k,j$ entry and zeroes elsewhere, 
$$
ME_{kj}N=M_kN_j,
$$
where $M_k$ is the $k^{\rm th}$ column of $M$ and $N_j$ with the $j^{\rm th}$ row of $j$. By the previous case, one of them has to be zero. So if $M$ has a nonzero column, then $N=0$; and if $N$ has a nonzero row, then $M=0$.